# Combining WHERE and CASE with multiple conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have 3 conditions in my WHERE clause :

```
FD.NAME = @fraude
AND substring(eei.NAME,1,12) != '##ORIGINAL##'
DOCTYP.LABEL = 'Facture'
```

I want to modify my third condition, something like:

```
    select .......
    where
    FD.NAME = @fraude
    AND substring(eei.NAME,1,12) != '##ORIGINAL##'
(CASE WHEN @fraude = 0
    THEN
DOCTYP.LABEL <> 'Facture'
WHEN @fraude = 1 THEN
    DOCTYP.LABEL = 'Facture'
end)
```

When  @fraude is 0 change the operator to "<>" else "=", but this is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
AND substring(eei.NAME,1,12) != '##ORIGINAL##'
AND 
(
(
    @fraude = 0
AND
    DOCTYP.LABEL <> 'Facture'
) 
OR
(
    @fraude = 1 
AND
    DOCTYP.LABEL = 'Facture'
)
)
```

No need to use case

Comment: Happy to help. Accept the answer if it suffice your requirement :)